# UIView Fullscreen Problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to get my UIView to fill the entire screen. I've tried the code below, which works, but always leaves a white line where the status bar was below. No matter what size i set the frame of the `UIView`, this line always remains there. What am I missing?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide]; 
[view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
[view setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: How do you add this to the view hierarchy?

Comment: It's a subview of a UIViewController. So: `[self.view addSubview:view]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly likely that your view controller's view's frame was set to the `applicationFrame` and since you're adding the `view` as it's subview, the frame of your `view` will be within its parent view's bounds.

You will have to adjust the view controller's view first and then follow it up by adding the view.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide]; 

self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[view setNeedsLayout];
```

You will also need to set the `autoresizingMask` if you think `self.view.frame` might change.

Comment: FYI: I discovered that when you're in a View, in iOS 5, `self.window` gives `<nil>` whereas in iOS 6 you'll get the key window. since I was in a view (not in a view controller), I resulted using